# Rspecでcan't convert RSpec::Mocks::Double to Arrayエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rails4.0に上げてRspec2.99にしたところテストでエラーが出るようになりました。

```
エラー。, can't convert RSpec::Mocks::Double to Array (RSpec::Mocks::Double#to_ary gives RSpec::Mocks::Double)
2015/11/25 15:31:39 [INFO] ::
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:347:in `Array'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:347:in `block in options_for_select'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:346:in `map'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:346:in `options_for_select'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb:22:in `render'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:156:in `select'
    /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:774:in `select'
    /poge/hoge/workspace/version/app/pogeapp/app/helpers/common_form_builder.rb:157:in `block in select_frame'
```

Rspecを[バージョンアップ](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/209109)すれば解決するのでしょうか？
selectボックスを表示する箇所でエラーが出るようになりました。実際に表示してもエラーにはなりません。

実コードデバックしたやつです。listsに配列を入れてセレクトボックスで出そうとしてるだけです。

```
157       select(:hogeid, lists, options, {:class => span12}) +
(byebug) p lists
[Hoge:0x3fcd6a333844 @name="Hoge_11"]
(byebug) p options
{}
```

テストコード、レスポンスがエラーにならないことを確かめてます。

```
let(:lists){mock_model(Hoge).as_null_object}

     before(:each) do
       get :new_hogehoge, params
     end
     it "エラーにならない" do
       response.should be_success
     end
```

Comment: コードを見ないとなんとも言えない部分があるので、動かしているRSpecのコードとcommon_form_builder.rbのコード（157行目付近）を追記してもらえると助かります。

Comment: コード、テストを追記いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

詳しい理由はわかりませんが、mock_model + as_null_object にすると、事前にセットアップしていないメソッド呼び出しは常に自分自身（つまり null object）を返す仕様になっているようです。（最新版でも同様）

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-activemodel-mocks/blob/master/spec/rspec/active_model/mocks/mock_model_spec.rb#L286

```
it "returns self for any unprepared message" do
  @model.as_null_object.tap do |x|
    expect(x.non_existant_message).to be(@model)
  end
end
```

また、質問のエラーはnull objectを引数（下記コードの`r`）にして Kernel#Array() を呼びだしているところで発生しています。

action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:347:in `Array'

```
selected, disabled = extract_selected_and_disabled(selected).map do |r|
  Array(r).map { |item| item.to_s }
end
```

Kernel#Array() は渡されたオブジェクトに対して、`to_ary`と`to_a`を呼び出します。
配列以外のオブジェクトはこの呼び出しを無視すべきなのですが、null objectは（意味もなく）自分自身を返してしまうため、エラーが起きたようです。

というわけで、null objectに対して、`to_ary`と`to_a`の呼び出しを無視する（nilを返す）ように振る舞いを定義すると、おそらくうまくいきます。

```
let(:lists) do
  mock_model(Hoge).as_null_object.tap do |hoge|
    allow(hoge).to receive(:to_ary).and_return(nil)
    allow(hoge).to receive(:to_a).and_return(nil)
  end
end
```

こちらの環境（RSpec 2.99 + Rails 4.0.13）ではこれでうまくいきました。
一度試してみてください。

Comment: うまくいきました！mock_model + as_null_object を使う際は注意が必要ということですね、ありがとうございます。