# rspec2.99からrspec3.0.1に上げたらundefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClassエラー発生

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rspec

rspec2.99でテストが全部OKになった状態でrspec3.0.1に上げたら以下エラーが出るようになりました。

```
 2015/12/08 10:36:23 [ERROR] :: ref:[e92-35e1] type:[APPLICATION_ERROR] システムエラー。, undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
 2015/12/08 10:36:23 [INFO] ::
         /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:24:in `html_escape'
         /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:10:in `render'
         /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:771:in `text_field'
         /poge/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1262:in `text_field'
         /poge/hoge/workspace/transpec4.0/app/views/hogehoges/_form.html.erb:119:in `block (4 levels) in _app_views_hogehoges__form_html_erb__287475598865390515_70183742838460'
```

エラーが出ている箇所のform.html.erbはテキストを表示しようとしています。

```
                <%= f.text_field :hoge_memo, :placeholder => t('.input.hoge_memo') %>
```

テストコードはレスポンスを正常なことを確認しており、mock1にhoge_memoを定義するとエラーは出なくなりました。が、同じようにエラーになっている箇所が多くあり全部定義する以外に修正方法は無いでしょうか？

```
 -  let(:p1){{:name => "hoge"}}
 +  let(:p1){{:name => "hoge", :hoge_memo=>3,:dispname => "hogehoge"}}
    let(:mock1) do
      mock_model(HogeHoge, p1).as_null_object.tap do |hoge|
        allow(hoge).to receive(:to_ary).and_return(nil)
        allow(hoge).to receive(:to_a).and_return(nil)
      end
    end


        before(:each) do
          allow(HogeHoge).to receive(:new).and_return(mock1)
          get :new
        end
        it "レスポンス200" do
          expect(response).to be_succes
```

エラー箇所はgems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb
の24行目でsにnilが渡ってきてgsubメソッドが無いとエラーになっているようです。

```
 19     def html_escape(s)
 20       s = s.to_s
 21       if s.html_safe?
 22         s
 23       else
 24         s.gsub(/[&"'><]/, HTML_ESCAPE).html_safe
 25       end
 26     end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません。[こちらの問題](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19299/rspec%E3%81%A7cant-convert-rspecmocksdouble-to-array%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B)に派生して出ていたエラーでした。

```
can't convert RSpec::Mocks::Double to String (RSpec::Mocks::Double#to_str gives RSpec::Mocks::Double)
```

上のエラーが出ていましてmockのto_aryとto_aの呼び出しを無視するスタブを呼ぶことで解決しました。

Comment: 自己解決されたということ良かったです。ただ、モックを多用しすぎているためにいろいろと問題が発生しているようにも見えます。モックは「用法用量をお守りください」系のテクニックなので、「どうしても」という場面以外は使わない方がベターです。特にnull_objectは「ブラックホール」的な動きをするので予想の付かないエラーが発生しがちです。また、モックを使うと「テストコードはパスしているのに本番環境ではエラーが出た（その逆もしかり）」なんてことも起こりえます。質問のコードを見る限り、普通にデータベースにテストデータを作成する形でも問題ない気がします。というわけで、個人的には「モックを使わないテストコードへの移行」を検討してみることをオススメします。

Comment: 確かにモックに関して以下ワーニングも出るようになりました。
`Using `as_null_object` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated.`

量が多いので今回対応できるか分かりませんが「モックを使わないテストコードへの移行」も検討してみます。